# Woocommerce Product to fix variation set default quanity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to set default quantity for all product same variables. 1 piece for first variation, 2 piece for second variation, 3 piece for third variation.
Actually there is some problem with for cycle.
I would thank, for someone who can help. :)

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_min_max_qty', 10, 3 );
function custom_variation_min_max_qty( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    // Your variable product ID
    $variable_id = $product->get_id();
    $qtym =0;
    if( $product->get_id() == $variable_id ) {
        // Set 1st variation ID
        for ($i=1; $i++; ) {
         if( $variation->get_id() == $i ){
            $qty = $qtym +1; // Set the quantity
            $qtym=$qty;
        }
            if ($i > 1000) {
        break;
    }
        }
        }
    if( isset($qty) ) {
        $data['min_qty'] = $qty;
        $data['max_qty'] = $qty;
    }
    return $data;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation',  'change_variation_input_quantity_script' );
function change_variation_input_quantity_script() {
    global $product;
    // Your variable product ID
    $variable_id = $product->get_id();
    if( $product->get_id() != $variable_id ) return;
    // Output Javascript
    ?>
    <!-- JS Thankyou Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var a = 'div.quantity > input.qty';
        // On load
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(a).val($(a).prop('min'));
        }, 300);
        // On change / select a variation
        $('.variations_form select').on( 'blur', function(){
            if( $('input[name="variation_id"]').val() > 0 )
                $(a).val($(a).prop('min'));
        })
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`woocommerce_available_variation`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-product-variable.html#source-view.364) hook is executed for each product variation.

It is found inside the `get_available_variation()` method which in turn is executed inside the `get_available_variations()` method of the `WC_Product_Variable` class.

If you want to set the quantity of the product (min and max) like this:

- **Variation 1**:

  - `min_qty` => 1
  - `max_qty`  => 1
- **Variation 2**:

  - `min_qty` => 2
  - `max_qty`  => 2
- **Variation 3**:

  - `min_qty` => 3
  - `max_qty`  => 3

etc...

You can use the following function:

```
// set custom quantities to product variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_min_max_qty', 10, 3 );
function custom_variation_min_max_qty( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    // initializes the number (position) of the product variation
    $i = 1;
    // for each product variation
    foreach ( $product->get_children() as $variation_id ) {
        // if the id of the product variation is equal to the id of the current variation
        if ( $variation_id == $variation->get_id() ) {
            // sets the min and max values with the current position
            $data['min_qty'] = $i;
            $data['max_qty'] = $i;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*